# ¿Cómo listos todos los archivos de un directorio incluyendo el número de línea?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Me gustaría tener una salida como la de `ls -1` pero que cada línea esté numerada, por ejemplo:

```
1)archivo.txt 
2)archivo.bat
3)apuntes.md
```

mi idea es hacer un bucle `while` desde 0 a n(n=numero de lineas del comando ls -1),que lo he calculado con `wc` y que en cada iteración escriba el numero de la iteración mas la linea .

sabeis si con grep,awk o sed se puede?
gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo final que persigues?

Answer (score 3):

Una forma bien sencilla, aunque no es la idea inicial que tienes y siempre que te sirva el formato que genera, es combinar el `ls` con el comando [`nl - number lines of files`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl), de la siguiente forma:

```
ls -1 | nl -s")"
```

La salida de `ls` la dirigimos mediante el pipe a la entrada del comando `nl` el cual numerará cada línea y agregando como separador el paréntesis `-s")`"

Comment: Qué interesante, no conocía `nl`

Answer (score 1):

`cat fichero` sirve para imprimir un fichero con el número de línea al lado.

Del mismo modo, se puede leer la salida de otro comando haciendo `cat <<< "$(comando)"`:

```
$ cat <<< "$(echo 'hola')"
hola
```

Por ello, puedes decir:

```
cat -n <<< "$(ls -1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Las dos opciones dadas son buenísimas. Tanto `nl` por 'ir al grano', como la de @fedorqui por mostrar las potencialidades de `bash`. Aunque quizás con `cat -n` se podría pasar a través de un pipe en lugar de un *command substitution*.

### Con `awk`.

También se puede con `awk`.

```
\ls | awk -v OFS=')' '{print NR,$1}'
```

Donde `\ls` (con la diagonal invertida) corre el comando como tal, sin alias, y `awk` imprime el número de renglón, separado por el *output file separator* (`OFS`) ")", seguido de la salida del primer campo. En otras palabras, numera la salida de `ls`.

Otra opción que sería engorrosísima sería:

```
\ls | awk -v OFS=")" '{_[NR]=$1}END{for (elemento in _) print elemento,_[elemento]}'
```

Donde ingreso los elementos a un array con un índice igual al número de registro y su valor como el elemento de la lista. Al final los imprimo con un `for` separados por el OFS definido como `")"`.

### Con `grep`.

```
\ls | \grep -n ""
```

En este caso, el flag `-n` de `grep` enumera las líneas, pero no te pondría por defecto el separador ')' sino dos puntos (`:`) (luego podrías procesarlo para obtener la salida que quieras).

### Con `sed`.

Se puede con sed pero es un tanto "diferente", de hecho la solución que se me ocurre es con un doble uso.

```
\ls | sed -n '=;p' | sed '$!N;s/\n/)/'
```

La primera parte de `sed` numera las lineas y luego las imprime. La segunda parte busca los saltos de línea, los reemplaza por un paréntesis (`s/\n/) /`), y, sino es es el fin de la línea, entonces añade la linea siguiente a la linea actual.

### Con `python`

Lo mismo si tienes `python` podrías hacerlo en un *one-liner*, aunque sería algo ofuscado.

```
\ls | python -c 'import sys; print("\n".join("{}){}".format(*x) for x in enumerate(sys.stdin.read().split() ) ))'
```

Lo importante aquí (al menos para mi) es que se muestra cómo utilizar el *stdin* del comando anterior dentro de un script en `python`.

### Con `perl`.

```
\ls | perl -ne 'print "$.)$_" '
```

Aquí `perl` con `-n` indica que se itere sobre lo ingresado y `-e` indica que se va a ingresar un comando de una línea. El comando imprime el número de registro (`$.`) seguido de un paréntesis y luego un espacio, seguido del último registro (`$_`).